# Talend run-if none triggered

Tags: talend

I have several run-if conditions.I could have a catch all that ANDs and NOTs the several run-if conditions to run when none of them trigger.

Is there an alternative method to have a path chosen when none of the run-if conditions returned true?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "else" link in Talend to do that automatically.
One solution would be to rewrite a condition which is the negative of all the others one combined.

Otherwise, **if** you can check the condition on your input flow (e.g : "XX"!=row1.myData), you can direct your flow on a tMap , and have multiple outputs on your tMap : each output could be filtered with one condition, and you can have a resulting output with "catch output reject" option. *Only doable if the condition is on a data on the flow.*

[image]